# Combine two query into one query

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, union

I would like to calculate the number of items sold on sale date and the TOTAL number of items.
I know how to write then separately on two queries. I tried to write them into one query using union, it is not working. I've stuck here and any comments are welcoming

I would like to write one query to get number of items sold on sale date, sold not on sale date.

Here are my codes:

```
SELECT COUNT(T.items) AS total_items FROM Transaction AS T JOIN Sale AS S ON T.ID = S.ID ;

SELECT COUNT(T.items) AS discount_items FROM Transaction AS T JOIN Sale AS S ON T.ID = S.ID 
WHERE S.sale_date = T.date
```

I would like to use one query to get total_items and discount_items.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the queries as:

```
SELECT COUNT(T.items) AS total_items,
       SUM(CASE WHEN S.sale_date = T.date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as discount_items
FROM Transaction T JOIN
     Sale S
     ON T.ID = S.ID ;
```

I don't know if this will be useful, but it answers your question.